# How to make Martian soil

Tags: geology, soil, mars, soil-science

My son wants to replicate some experiments and try to grow plants in Martian soil for his A-level science project. I know NASA have managed to produce soil that mimics Martian soil, however I also know how expensive it is.

My question is, what is the closest proxy to real Martian soil that I can create in the kitchen using readily available supplies from builders merchants, garden suppliers, chemists, and supermarkets?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Needs to be merged with: https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/19017/7

Comment: voting to close as a duplicate of this [exact duplicate](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/19017/how-to-make-martian-soil). related meta: https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1814/6031